# IIS/HttpHandler: Get relative absolute path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, path

I've got a site setup in IIS to run at `http://localhost/WebApplication6`. In my web application I have a handler (implements `IHttpHandler`). When I print `context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath`, I get `/WebApplication6/whaetever`. I want to trim off `/WebApplication6` (the local site name). How can I do that? Is there a way to get the "WebApplication6" bit so I know what to trim off? (inside [IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest.aspx)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet would be [HttpRequest.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.apprelativecurrentexecutionfilepath.aspx) - it provides path relative to your web application root directory. However, it will be in form of "`~/whatever`" where `~/` indicates app relative path. If your requirement is to get `/whatever` then you can strip off ~ using string functions.

BTW, here's good article that will help you make sense of all paths: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/132081.aspx

Comment: Yep, that'll do 'er. Also discovered `Request.ApplicationPath` which gives me just the `/WebApplication6` bit so I can modify the URLs that way too.

Answer (score 0):

```
VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
```

Comment: this will not work. In fact, it would always give directory portion i.e. `/foo/bar/` will give `/foo/`.